# Joomla pagination in back-end links to wrong pages

Tags: joomla, pagination, joomla1.7

I am trying to convert a 1.5 component to a 1.7 one. SO far everything works except pagination.

What happens is:

- clicking the menu option "guides" in component-menu brings up an overview page.
- clicking on a button called "guide-list" brings up a list of guides and the pagination-bar at the bottom. But whenever I click anything on that pagination-bar I am brought back to the overview page.

What i have in **view.html.php:**

```
function display($tpl = null) {

  $items = $this->get('Items');
  $pagination = $this->get('Pagination');
  $this->state = $this->get("State");

  if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))) {
     JError::raiseError(500, implode('<br />', $errors));
     return false;
  }

  $this->items = $items;
  $this->children = $items;
  $this->pagination = $pagination;

  $this->addToolBar();

  parent::display($tpl);
```

}

and in the **default.php** template I simply put:

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->getListFooter(); ?>
```

according to all the tutorials and articles I read about 1.6 and 1.7 this should work out of the box. So either I made a mistake or there is more to pagination that this?

ADDITIONAL:
While I was working on another aspect I read somewhere that in the template the form attribute name should not be used. So I changed:

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_guides'); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm">
```

into:

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_guides'); ?>" method="post" id="adminForm">
```

Oddly enough, this changes the behaviour of the pagination links. The old name-attribute takes me back to the overvioew page while the new id-attribute keeps  me on the same page. This problem is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

I compared my own code to several different other components and I fail to see why this would be the solution, but somehow it suddenly works when I change the code in the template default.php into:

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_guides&view=guides'); ?>" method="post" id="adminForm" name="adminForm">
```

in other words, I have to specify both the id and name attributes AND include the &view=guides in the URL.
I see other components doing it like this, but yet others seem to work fine without this. So I do suspect that it depends on something else as well.

Comment: Adding the view parameter is the right approach. I do not know, where you have seen extensions, that work without specifying the view, but basically the joomla naming conventions will fall back to the default view if none is defined here. Refer to the com_banners for example and you'll find that clients-, tracks- and banners-view all have this attribute specified. I had the same issue and found that copy pasting caused the error since i forgot to update this part ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're view code looks good, so I'll start off by guessing that your issue lies in your data model. It sounds like you're either not saving your user state information properly, or you're overriding your view state when you submit the form. What are your POST parameters when you click on the pagination bar? Make sure there are no "task" or "view" variables being passed back to Joomla. Did you write your own getPagination() and populateState() methods? You're most-likely being re-routed to your "guides" view by your controller, which is presumably reacting to a change in either the "task" or "view" variables that is being passed to Joomla.

Comment: I did not write my own getPagination() or populateState() methods (yet). The POST parameters are controller=guides&option=com_guides&view=guides# 
You are right, I tried changing the default view in my controller and it changed the way I was redirected. So I am wondering if the hash (#) is the problem?

Comment: Obviously that was silly of me, the hash will not be a problem. Strangely enough, if I change the code in the default.php template to echo $this->pagination->getPagesLinks() and click one of those, I will remain on the same page (so I am neither taken back to the overview page nor to the next page). I am beginning to suspect a bug?

Answer (score 0):

i used

$this->pagination = $this->get('Pagination');

and mine was okay. just had to add that to the view.html.php, then added

pagination->getListFooter(); ?>

to default.php and it works perfectly, no additional coding